# Automatically call function after materialized view refresh?

Tags: postgresql, view, triggers, materialized-views

Most question I've seen regarding materialized views and automation concerned either refreshing views periodically or refreshing them on some trigger.

It could be said, that my problem is reverse of that.
Given some materialized view, I'd like to call some function that inserts some rows into some other table. So, basically something like "create trigger  after refresh on ".
The problem is, there's no such trigger type as "after refresh".

Is it achievable natively in Postgres?

Comment: Interesting use case! I'm not aware of such triggers. Would a trigger on the origin table(s) to call this function be an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that is with an [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) that fires `ON ddl_​command_​end`.

Check for `TG_TAG = 'REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW'` in the function body.
Check the `objid` in the result of `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()` to know which materialized view was refreshed.